# how to avoid -bash: command not found error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

Here is my script:

```
zio=build-mac-zio
x="zio"
y=${!x}
```

When I try `echo $y`, I get `build-mac-zio` as expected. However when I execute this command:

```
mkdir -p $JENKINS_URL/bkp/jobs/$y/builds/
```

I get the following message:

```
-bash: build-mac-zio: command not found
```

How can I access `$y` and use it to assign to other variables.

Comment: "When I try to access `$y`" — are you trying to run it as a command? Tell us what you want to do with it. (If you want to assign it to other variables, tell us why can't you use `$y` itself.)

Comment: no I am not using $y as a command.I am using it to create a directory dynamically as shown below "mkdir -p  $JENKINS_URL/bkp/jobs/$y/builds/" , but its not working.

Comment: Works for me. Please, show the exact command that causes the error.

Comment: alnet..if i can use ${zio} then there is no need for this question :)                                 @choroba,  as i mentioned in previous comment, I am using "mkdir -p $JENKINS_URL/bkp/jobs/$y/builds/"

Comment: Are you sure there is no whitespace around `=` or in your variables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm nervous about the lack of quotes. Try this:

```
dirname=$JENKINS_URL/bkp/jobs/$y/builds/
od -c <<<"$dirname"
```

Do you see any unexpected characters in there?

Comment: I am getting 
0000000   J   E   N   K   I   N   S   _   U   R   L   /   b   k   p   /
0000020   j   o   b   s   /   /   b   u   i   l   d   s   /  \n
0000036

Comment: Aside from $y being empty and $JENKINS_URL=="JENKINS_URL", there's nothing unusual in there. Execute that `od` command in the same context where you are seeing your mkdir error message.